# Asp.net - Creating 2 linked Drop Down Lists from Database

Tags: asp.net, database, drop-down-menu

I have 2 linked database tables (Similar to Country -> State) - how can I dynamically populate 2 drop down lists with these tables such that:

If I pick a Country, only the states for that country show up in the second drop down list?

Update:
There seems to be a solution on this page -> [Populate DropdownList based upon other DropDownList VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936499/populate-dropdownlist-based-upon-other-dropdownlist-vb) -> the one that uses the SQL Data connection on the aspx page itself, databinding the dropdowns - how do I do this with LINQ? I think I can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your state control hidden, and autopostback = true on your Country dropdownlist.

On the SelectedIndexChanged, you pull that value and query your database with that, and then set your state drop down list to visible.

In the ASPX page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CountryDD" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CountryDD_IndexChanged" />

<asp:DropDownList ID="StateDD" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
```

In the Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub CountryDD_IndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    StateDD.Items.Clear()
    Using conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Connection String")
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("get_states_by_country", conn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_id", CountryDD.SelectedValue)
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                StateDD.Items.Add(New ListItem(dr("state_name").ToString(), dr("state_id")))
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: This would require a postback and a page or update reload, correct?

Comment: Yes, it requires a postback, or being wrapped in an Ajax Toolkit UpdatePanel to make it look seamless.

Answer (score 1):

This will require one of two things:

1. Non-trivial JavaScript.  (Make it easier with JQuery.  Provide one set of data associating states with countries, and use JavaScript to create/populate the list each time the user selects a new country.
2. Lots of communication back and forth from the server.  (Each time the user picks a country, you ask the server for a new list of states, and use AJAX to update the state drop-down.)

Comment: Could you expand on how to do #2? I could use js, but I'd rather populate the fields from the database as that might be needed for this in the future.

Comment: Using JS and populating from the database are not separate options.  You can create some dynamic javascript with the database content, if you're so inclined.  #2 is better described in databyss' answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to using the Microsoft [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/), they have a control called the [Cascading Dropdown](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) that would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using one of the answers on [Populate DropdownList based upon other DropDownList VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936499/populate-dropdownlist-based-upon-other-dropdownlist-vb) - I put the 2 dropdowns in an AJAX Update Panel. This is the same as databyss's answer, except it uses data binding in the page definition itself, no back-end code required.

Code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="Countries" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"
            AutoPostBack="true"
        />
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="Countries" runat="server" 
            ContextTypeName="YourDataContext" 
            Select="new (Id, Name)" TableName="AssessmentTypes">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="States" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Id"
        />
        <asp:LinqDataSource ID="States" runat="server" 
            ContextTypeName="YourDataContext" 
            Select="new (Id, Name, CountryId)" TableName="Modules" 
            Where="CountryId == @CountryId">
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" DbType="Guid" 
                    Name="CountryId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </WhereParameters>
        </asp:LinqDataSource>    

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```